# How to use subquery as FROM in DQL

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql, zend-framework3

im using Zend Framwork 3 and Doctrine 2. I got a relatively complex DQL with multiple joins having and where clauses.

I now need to get some rowcounts for those queries with different paramters in the having clause. I thought a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (original-query) AS c` would be the easiest way to do so. But when trying to use a native query i get Problems with binding the paramters from the DQL to the native query and when trying to do sth. like

```
$queryBuilder->select('count(c)')->from('('.$originalQuery->getDQL().')', 'c');
```

i get :

```
Error: Class '(' is not defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

Seems to be you can't use it that way:

> Comment created by stof:
>
> DQL is about querying objects. Supporting subselects in the FROM
>   clause means that the DQL parser is not able to build the result set
>   mapping anymore (as the fields returned by the subquery may not match
>   the object anymore). This is why it cannot be supported (supporting it
>   only for the case you run the query without the hydration is a no-go
>   IMO as it would mean that the query parsing needs to be dependant of
>   the execution mode).
>
> In your case, the best solution is probably to run a SQL query instead
>   (as you are getting a scalar, you don't need the ORM hydration anyway)

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/3542

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But after using the expressions and calling $qb->getQuery()->getResult(); i get a similar error "Error: Class 'SELECT' is not defined."